# ¿Error de insert en JOOQ SQL?

Tags: java, jooq

Estoy trabajando en eclipse con JOOQ, pero en la linea donde realizo el insert me sale 'PREGUNTA cannot be resolve to a variable'. La tabla 'pregunta' ya la tengo creada en mysql.

```
public void insertarPregunta(AbsPregunta prta){

    try (java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password)) 
    {
        DSLContext create = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MYSQL);

        int id = prta.getId();
        String enunciado = prta.getEnunciado();

        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.alias("pregunta", AbsPregunta.class);

        String xml = xstream.toXML(prta);

        create.insertInto(PREGUNTA, PREGUNTA.ID, PREGUNTA.ENUNCIADO, PREGUNTA.OBJXML)
            .values(id, enunciado, xml)
            .execute();
    } 

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es un error de MySQL, es un erro de Java. ¿Dónde tienes declarada la variable `PREGUNTA` en tu código?

Answer (score 0):

Era un error de importación, tenia que añadir esta linea.

```
import static com.pretech.jooq.tables.Pregunta.PREGUNTA;
```